# Call a javascript function in MVC Razor View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to modify dynamically a class of a div when the status of a property changes in a Razor MVC View.

My View is (actually is a partial view):

```
@model xxxx.xxxx.StatusControlModel

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentStatus)

@if (Model.CurrentStatus.Equals("Offline"))
{
<text>
<script>

 Offline();
</script>
</text>
}
else
{
    <text>
     <script>

      Online();
     </script>
    </text>
}

<script>
function Online() {
    $("#dev").toggleClass("collist span_1_of_3offline", "collist span_1_of_3online");
};
function Offline() {
    $("#dev").toggleClass("collist span_1_of_3online", "collist span_1_of_3offline");
};
```

I want to change the class of a div in the main View with an ID of ''dev''.

The partialview is updated every 15 seconds using a Ajax setInterval. How can I change the class of this div?

Comment: within you ajax call, in your success function call Online(), in your error function call Offline();

Comment: I would recommend against putting javascript in a View but if you need to then I recommend moving the `<script>function Online()...` block to the top.

Comment: That could be a good idea. Unfortunately , in my ajax call, I only update the partialview. I cannot konw if the call is successful or not

Comment: I believe what you need is switchClass(), not toggleClass()

Comment: The 2nd parameter of `.toggleClass()` is a `bool` value. What are you attempting to do with this? And scripts should never be in partials.